# Why only Linux master branch visible on Github?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, development, github

Why is only the Linux master branch visible in the Github Repository?

https://github.com/torvalds/linux/branches

Is there a way to view the other branches?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linus’ kernel tree only has a master branch; see [the original](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/). That’s why you can’t see the other branches: there aren’t any. In the Linux development model, other branches are [other repositories](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/).